# Dave's Wordpress Live Search only works when logged in as admin

Tags: plugins, search

I am using Dave's Wordpress Live Search on my site www.frome.fm but it only works when logged in as admin. When logged out or browsing as guest the spinning icon shows for a second or two but then no results are displayed. I've tried disabling plugins to no avail. The wp-admin folder is not protected with .htaccess server side nor do I have relevanssi installed.

Answer (score 4):

That plugin uses the [AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) as it should...

```
http://frome.fm/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?s=ho&action=dwls_search
```

... but when not logged in that request fails (from HttpFox)...

```
07:23:58.923    0.155   470 0   GET (Aborted)   NS_BINDING_ABORTED  http://frome.fm/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?s=ho&action=dwls_search
```

Since you say that the plugin works when you are logged in the Ajax callback is likely hooked to `wp_ajax_*` but not `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` The latter is required for [requests made by non-logged in users](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).

You will need to find the plugin code that hooks the AJAX callback and add a second line of code to hook to `wp_ajax_nopriv_*`.

It is possible that the plugin performs other checks, however, so that may not be adequate. It is impossible to say without digging through the code.

Comment: I found this in the code


`// Set up the AJAX hooks
add_action( "wp_ajax_dwls_search", array( "DavesWordPressLiveSearchResults", "ajaxSearch" ) );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_dwls_search", array( "DavesWordPressLiveSearchResults", "ajaxSearch" ) );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( "DavesWordPressLiveSearchResults", "pre_get_posts" ) );`

Looks like it does already contain a wp_ajax_nopriv_* argument

Comment: Then see the _caveat_ in the last paragraph of my answer. The plugin must be doing something else. Find and post that `ajaxSearch` method.

Comment: `public function ajaxSearch() {
    $maxResults = intval(get_option('daves-wordpress-live-search_max_results'));
    if ($maxResults === 0)
      $maxResults = -1;`

Comment: @MatthewSims : Well... even more complicated. The plugin apparently keeps precalculated results in the options table... a bit strange.

Answer (score -1):

AHA!

Thanks for your help. You didn't post this as your direct answer but by giving me the HttpFox error I was able to track down a line in the admin-ajax file which defaulted the WP_ADMIN to true. By changing it to false it now works. Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you saying that you edited a Core file? You should not be doing that. It will cause trouble when you update and it may cause other issues as well. You are much better off pursuing a solution that does not include Core edits.

Comment: I agree s_ha_dum but it didn't work even with the standard wordpress themes such as 2011 or 2011 so it must be a server configuration but I do not really know what I'm looking for and the developer of the plugin could not work it out either. I'll answer your other post when I can get access to the code again.